# How can I get all the tags that have been applied to a file in a git repository?

Tags: git

When I do a `git log filename` or some listing of the commits that a file has been through, I'd like to see *all* the tags that were applied to the repository where the file was exactly the version specified   in the `git log filename`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, figure out the commit hash of the commit you are interested in -- in this example it is 6502bcc16b3790cc22cb771d1da3e8f35b4009c0:

```
$ git log «filename»
commit 6502bcc16b3790cc22cb771d1da3e8f35b4009c0
Author: Mike Morearty <mike@morearty.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 13 16:04:56 2012

    added «filename»
```

Then, use `git tag --contains` to ask for all tags that contain that commit:

```
$ git tag --contains 6502bcc16b3790cc22cb771d1da3e8f35b4009c0
tag1
tag2
```

If you want to do all of that in one line, here is one way (perhaps there are more efficient ways):

```
$ git tag --contains $(git log -1 --pretty=%H «filename»)
```

Comment: Excellent.  I didn't know about `--contains`. If I wanted to inline the tags in the complete log of the file, would I do something like this? `git log filename | perl -ne 'print $_; if (m/^commit (.*)/) { print "tags: ".\`git tag --contains $1\`;}'`

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Another thing you might like is adding `[log] decorate = true` to your `.gitconfig`. It adds tag and branch names to all `git log` commands (but not *all* tags, only ones that are at that exact spot).